# How to use % wildcard?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

```
public function searchItem($itemname) //search item based on itemname
{

    $itemname = (string)$itemname; 
    $select = $this->select() 
    ->from(array('item')) 
    ->where('itemname LIKE "%"?"%', $itemname);
    $row = $this->fetchAll($select);
    if (!$row) { //if row can't be found
        throw new Exception("Could not find row $itemname"); //Catch exception where itemid is not found


    }
    return $row->toArray();
}
```

Any idea on how to use the two '%'? I tried to use combinations of ' and " but it doesnt work, cant figure out what to use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you wish to escape them? Then they will no longer function as wildcards. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to use %itemname%. But the syntax is SELECT ... LIKE '%word%' so I want to escape the '. I hope you get what I mean, dont really know how to put it across.

Comment: It's entirely unclear why you'd want to escape the `%` because then they would no longer function as wildcards. Is that what you want? What is your eventual aim? What is your business requirement? In simple terms: **what did your boss ask you to implement**? (Assume your boss doesn't understand code... he only understands user features.)

Comment: nooooo this is for my school work. I want them to function as wildcards but I cant put ('itemname LIKE '%?%', $itemname) because it gives me an sql error.

Comment: Then that has absolutely nothing to do with escaping the `%`. Your question is misleading. Please try to reword your question to express what you are trying to achieve. Currently your question asks for a specific approach but that approach doesn't do what you want so correct answers to this question won't help you at all.

Comment: Or it might be better to just accept the answer and make a new question - the *real* question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\%` to escape the percent sign.

Note you can use PHPs [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to do this for you.